# How can I change app store region without providing new payment information?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

How can I change my country/region in iPhone settings when I don't have an address or payment information I want to share with Apple?

Comment: I’m putting a hold on this. Per our [ask] help guidance we don’t host questions on why Apple has made product decisions. Please edit this if you face a practical problem based on this restriction / decision.